# WebRTC Android native compilation issue in ubuntu 14.04 32-bit

Tags: android, android-ndk, ubuntu-14.04, webrtc, cross-compiling

I tried to compile webrtc native code.

Added here main reference link for installation step:

http://webrtc.org/native-code/android/
http://www.khirman.com/building-webrtc-libraries-android/

While executing

> "gclient runhooks"

getting error like this:

```
    umnteam@umn-desktop:~/webrtc_androd_latest$ gclient runhooks

________ running '/usr/bin/python -c import os,sys;script = os.path.join("trunk","check_root_dir.py");_ = os.system("%s %s" % (sys.executable,script)) if os.path.exists(script) else 0' in '/home/umnteam/webrtc_androd_latest'

________ running '/usr/bin/python -u src/sync_chromium.py --target-revision d66326c14bb70a1d61d75b096a9a344bc9a53c1a' in '/home/umnteam/webrtc_androd_latest'
Chromium already up to date:  d66326c14bb70a1d61d75b096a9a344bc9a53c1a

________ running '/usr/bin/python src/setup_links.py' in '/home/umnteam/webrtc_androd_latest'

________ running '/usr/bin/python src/build/landmines.py --landmine-scripts src/webrtc/build/get_landmines.py --src-dir src' in '/home/umnteam/webrtc_androd_latest'

________ running '/usr/bin/python src/third_party/instrumented_libraries/scripts/download_binaries.py' in '/home/umnteam/webrtc_androd_latest'

________ running 'download_from_google_storage --directory --recursive --num_threads=10 --no_auth --quiet --bucket chromium-webrtc-resources src/resources' in '/home/umnteam/webrtc_androd_latest'
Hook 'download_from_google_storage --directory --recursive --num_threads=10 --no_auth --quiet --bucket chromium-webrtc-resources src/resources' took 10.58 secs

________ running '/usr/bin/python src/webrtc/build/gyp_webrtc -Dextra_gyp_flag=0' in '/home/umnteam/webrtc_androd_latest'
Updating projects from gyp files...
/home/umnteam/webrtc_androd_latest/src/third_party/android_tools/ndk//toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-i686/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: 1: /home/umnteam/webrtc_androd_latest/src/third_party/android_tools/ndk//toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-i686/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
gyp: Call to '/home/umnteam/webrtc_androd_latest/src/third_party/android_tools/ndk//toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-i686/bin/*-gcc -print-libgcc-file-name' returned exit status 2 while in all.gyp.
Error: Command '/usr/bin/python src/webrtc/build/gyp_webrtc -Dextra_gyp_flag=0' returned non-zero exit status 1 in /home/umnteam/webrtc_androd_latest
```

Please help me to find out the issue

Comment: Please visit this article which is quite helpful for webrtc native development as well as compilation of webrtc native stack. [compilation_of_webRtc_Library](https://github.com/mail2chromium/Compile_WebRTC_Library_For_Android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved after upgrade my RAM. Always check RAM usage while compiling webRTC. It will solve most of the issues.